# SPA Asp.Net Core Architecture

Tags: asp.net, angular, real-time

I want to build web app with real time communications with other web app via WebSocket.

For making WS one connection it's better to build SPA app.

Unfortunattely Angular 2 + Asp.Net Core seems not to be clear and stable. 
Furthermore I want to use Asp.Core libraries such as Identity

May be its better  to use ViewComponents and reloads them according to WS messages without reloading View?

Any Idea about better app architecture?

Answer (score 15):

Friend, you appear to be in way, way, way over your head. Let me just provide some very basic assistance to try and move you in the right direction.

If you are going to be using `ASP.NET` or `ASP.NET CORE` for real-time communications, you would likely use the `ASP.NET SignalR` library. `SignalR` (https://www.asp.net/signalr) supports `Web Sockets` but falls back to other techniques for older browsers which do not support them. It is very feature rich and integrates well with legacy `ASP.NET` or `ASP.NET Core`. (Microsoft provides versions for both.)

`ASP.NET Core` is stable now, but it is still not feature complete--particularly in regards to Entity Framework. However, for most green-field applications, that is to say, most new development, `ASP.NET Core` is a perfectly reasonable development choice. `ASP.NET Core` offers many great benefits--like the ability to deploy your .NET code on a Linux server. Application builds are much faster than legacy `.NET` (e.g. `.NET 4.6`).

Yes, `ASP.NET Identity` is a great choice for Identity Management (although I typically use IdentityServer4.) You will most certainly need to extend `ASP.NET Identity` to use it. (For example, most people extend `AppUser` with custom user properties. For a Single Page Application, you will probably also want to use `JSON Web Tokens` (JWT) (https://jwt.io/)). There are many other extensions to `ASP.NET Identity` you can (and probably will) make. They all require some basic familiarity with `ASP.NET Identity`'s internal architecture. (I recommend the tutorials from Taiseer Joudeh. (http://bitoftech.net/category/asp-net-identity/) They are for `ASP.NET 4.x` but can be easily migrated to `ASP.NET Core`. The output of these tutorials can also form a really great foundation for your own identity system.

To develop a `SPA` (`Single Page Application`), you are going to want to use a front-end framework. By far, the two most popular frameworks are Google's `Angular2` (http://angular.io) and Facebook's `React` (https://facebook.github.io/react/).

Based on what I am gathering from your post, you may not have much experience in these technologies. `ASP.NET Core`, `SignalR`, the (necessary) extension of `ASP.NET Identity`, `Angular2/React`, all have significant learning curves. By significant, I really mean SIGNIFICANT--which you can measure in months.

You will need to be familiar with `Gulp` to use as a Task runner under `ASP.NET Core`. I recommend using `Visual Studio 2015` or `Visual Studio 2017` for `ASP.NET Core` development. You can also get by quite nicely with `Visual Studio Code`.

Beyond that, there are a whole host of other tools you need to be familiar with to effectively develop for these platforms--particularly on the front-end.

For example, to do effective `Angular2` development (which is my recommendation for SPA front ends), you are going are really going to need to know or be able to use all of the following: `Git`, `ES6`, `TypeScript`, `RxJS`, `JSON`, `Node`, `NPM`, `angular-cli`, `Jasmine`, `Karma`, `Protractor`, `CSS`, `Sass/SCSS`, `Bootstrap` or `Angular Material`, `Webpack`, `Angular Universal`, etc. There are actually quite a few other tools/libraries you will want to utilize, but this will give you a good enough starting point.

On the client front end, you will most assuredly **not** want want to use `Visual Studio`. It is a real pain to set up for front-end `JavaScript` development. (The Angular2 setup for Visual Studio 2015/2017 is a bear.) You will probably use `Visual Studio Code`, `Sublime Text`, `Atom`, or `Webstorm`.

Most organizations employ an entire team of people to work on SPA apps. Some of the team members may include the following: Graphic Designer, CSS Themer, Front-End Javascript Developer, Back-End Server Developer, DBA/Data Architect, Requirements Analyst, Build/Testing Specialist, Tester, Network Administrator, and Project Manager. Of course, in many projects, one person may fill multiple roles--or people may share roles. The key point is that SPA projects are complex enough that most projects have at least 2-3 team members--and often more. Even then, very experienced folks can still struggle to get those apps into production.

One question that I would also ask you is, "Do you really need a `Single Page Application`?" `SPA`s are great--really great! However, they require significantly more knowledge to develop and have much more complexity than other applications. If there is a good use case for developing an `SPA`, then more power to you. If not, then you might consider stepping back and doing something a little less ambitious until you get a better handle on what is possible.

I am not saying all of this to discourage you. I am simply trying to paint a realistic picture of what you need to be able to actually build and deploy a production `SPA`. I want you to know what you are getting yourself into and have somewhat of a guided path to success.

Good luck out there, my friend!

---

**Update:** Added more detail on my current tool-set from a letter to a friend.

I have a good friend who is wanting to become a Web developer. I recently laid out a road map to assist him in his studies. I am simply copying and pasting that road map (and my letter to him) here to provide some additional details on the tools that I use (and mentioned above) along with some hint on the relative effort required to use them. He is just starting out so my descriptions of the tools are relatively non-technical. These are merely the ones I use, so please don't flame me if I left out your favorites.

---

...I wanted to go ahead and offer you a roadmap of where we are going by giving you a preview of the tools that I actually am using right now in my "development stack." (A "development stack" is the list of tools a person uses to code, build, and deploy projects.) Eventually, you will probably be using most of these tools (with the possible exception of some of the back-end development tools) or others that come after and replace them. This "stack" represents the tools that many of he top developers tend to use--although every developer has his own favorites. If you are going to jump head-first into this Web development career, then I am assuming you are going to want to be the best--because that is where the most rewarding projects are to be found--and the most lucrative ones as well.

As you read this list, you will probably be a bit overwhelmed by the sheer number of tools. I do this everyday, and I am still a bit overwhelmed by it. First, let me say that I do not necessarily use every tool everyday, but I do use every one of these tools sometimes. They are all indispensable to have in your arsenal. Second, let me also say that I am not an expert in every tool. You won't need to be either. There will be some tools that you absolutely master, some tools for which you need a very strong working knowledge, and some tools you just need the basics to get you by.

As we go forward, I am going to help you move in a very organized way of learning these tools. There are thousands of tools out there--many of which are useless or inferior. Knowing which tools you actually need will help focus you and prevent a lot of wasted time as you learn and grow. Beyond that, I will help you to get acquire the right knowledge in the right order to make the learning process as efficient and comfortable as possible.

It is perfectly fine for you to go ahead and begin to get familiar with some of these tools on your own. If you visit a site page and it all looks like gibberish now, don't worry about it. In a short while, it will all begin to make sense.

One thing I would note is that new tools are being introduced everyday. The technology is constantly evolving. I fully expect that, by the time you reach a moderate level of proficiency (some months from now), some of these tools may have begun to fade or even have been replaced entirely by others. Regardless, having learned the current incarnation of a tool will allow you to easily master the replacement tool.

I have categorized the tools in a somewhat logical order and provided a description for each tool; a link to a website; the required mastery level (`Basic [working knowledge]|Strong [working knowledge]|Expert`); and the approximate learning curve (assuming you were studying these things full time) to reach the required level of proficiency. Please note that many of the tools (e.g. code editors) can be used to some minimum level with a much lesser learning curve.

**Code Editors**

The first thing you are going to need for development is a good code editor. All of these are free (or have free or unlimited evaluation editions). I generally use `Visual Studio Code` for my front-end (Browser / JavaScript) development and Visual Studio 2017/Visual Studio Code for my back-end development (server side development.)

In addition to the core application, all of these have extensive libraries of community plugins. You will want to familiarize yourself with the available plugins and choose the ones which suit your needs and interests.

- `Visual Studio Code` - http://code.visualstudio.com/ - Expert, 1 Day
- `Sublime Text 3` - https://www.sublimetext.com/3 - Expert, 1 Day
- `Atom` - https://atom.io/ - Strong, 4 Hours
- `Visual Studio 2017` - https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/ - Expert, 1 Week

**Core Web Technologies**

`HTML 5` - The core markup language of the Web. The structure of of Web page is defined in `HTML`. This is fundamental to everything else we will learn. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5 - Expert, 1 Week

`Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) 3` - While `HTML` defines the structure of Web pages, `CSS` defines the thematic or stylistic elements (e.g. color, typographic, spacing of elements, etc.) of a page. `CSS` provides the "look and feel" of a page. For many good reasons, the structual and stylistic elements are kept entirely separate. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS3 - Expert, 2 Weeks

`JavaScript / EcmaScript / ES5` - `JavaScript` is the primary development language for the front-end--that is, to say, the browser. It handles much of the "interactivity" on a Web page but also provides functionality for sending data to and receiving data from the server in the background. `JavaScript` is the essential ingredient in modern Web applications. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript, Expert, 1 Month

**Core Web Technologies Plus**

While the core technologies are essential for any Web development project, they are simply not enough for serious Web projects. A number of frameworks and related tools have been developed on top of these technologies to either extend their capabilities or simplify their implementation.

`Bootstrap 3/4` - `Bootstrap` is a `CSS` framework that simplfies theming sites and also makes them much more standard. `CSS` theming can be very tricky and difficult. However, `Bootstrap` will greatly speed your development. The current version of `Bootstrap` is 3. Version 4 is in alpha. We will learn both as version 4 primarily extends (and further simplifies 3.) We will learn `Bootstrap 3` also because it is helpful in learning `Bootstrap 4` and most companies are still using it--so you will probably need to know it. http://getbootstrap.com/ - Expert, 1 Week

`Sass / SCSS / Syntactically Awesome Style Sheets` - `CSS` can be tricky, cumbersome, and very time consuming. Theming a website can take days or even a week or more. This is time that can be filled with much pain and many tears. Most of the frustrations in `CSS` come from the way different browsers implement (or fail to implement) the standards. `Sass` is known as a "`CSS pre-processor`" and helps to speed CSS development and also helps to fill in the gaps for functionality vendors failed to implement in a standard way. `Sass` (or its latest `SCSS` implementation) will eventually become your trusted and well-loved friend. http://sass-lang.com/

`Google Fonts` - Typography can make a mediocre Website really "pop." Google provides many free Web fonts that can be used easily in any site. https://fonts.google.com/ - Strong, 2 Hours

`Font Awesome` - `Font Awesome` provides many useful and standard icons which can be included on websites. You will make use of `Bootstrap`, `Google Fonts`, and `Font Awesome` in almost all your projects. They all work well together. - http://fontawesome.io/ - Strong, 2 Hours

`ES6 / EcmaScript 6 / ES 2015 / EcmaScript 2015` - Plain old `JavaScript` (`ES5`) has some serious limitations. A newer version of the language was released in 2015 which adds some much needed functionality. Unfortunately, not all browsers support this latest version. Fortunately, there are translators (called transpilers (e.g. `Babel`)) which can allow us to write `ES6` code and then translate it back into the older `JavaScript` that browsers understand. We will definitely be mastering `JavaScript`, `ES6`, and its successor (`TypeScript`, described below.) - http://es6-features.org/ - Expert, 2 Weeks

`TypeScript` - While one could consider `ES6` to be a wrapper around plain `JavaScript` that provides additional functionalities, `TypeScript` can be viewed as a wrapper around `ES6` which provides newer `JavaScript` functionality which was not part of the `ES6` standard. In other words, `TypeScript` > `ES6` > `JavaScript` (`ES5`). Just like with `ES6`, `TypeScript` can be translated (transpiled) back into either `ES6` or `ES5`. `Angular 2` uses `TypeScript` for its development. A mastery of `TypeScript` will not only be necessary for other Web development, but it is also necessary for learning and mastering `Angular 2`. NOTE: Eventually, all of functionality in TypeScript will make it's way into the browser (as will `ES6`) and the transpilation step will no longer be required. - Expert, 2 Weeks

`Babel` - `Babel` is the tool you will use to tranform or transpile `ES6` to plain old `ES5 JavaScript`. The tool is very simple to use. Most of the time, this will be managed for you in the background (by your build system - `Webpack` or `Gulp`). Still, it is necessary to have a basic working knowledge of the tool. - https://babeljs.io/ - Basic - 4 Hours

`(Google) Chrome Debugger` OR `Safari Web Tools` - Both Google and Safari are based on a browser engine called `Webkit` (https://webkit.org/.) Both include essential (and almost identical) tools for debugging Web pages. You will need to absolutely master the `Chrome Debugging tools`, and this is something that will eventually happen with continued use. You'll spend some time initially getting familiar with these tools and will then proceed to a deeper more intimate knowledge of them as you use them. - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools - 1 Day

**Web Frameworks**

`Angular 2` - Leading `JavaScript` framework provided by Google for developing "modern Web applications." `Angular 2` is very much the future of the Web. It is fast and powerful. `Angular 2` developers are also in extreme demand and are very well ($$$) paid. This is the first framework we will learn, and it has a fairly steep learning curve. We won't even begin to study it until we have a near mastery of `JavaScript`, `ES6`,and `TypeScript`. - http://angular.io. - Expert, 1-2 Months.

`React` - Leading framework provided by Facebook for developing "modern Web applications." Frankly, I am not a huge fan of React, but many developers love it. I think you definitely should learn it because 1) there are many React jobs, and 2) learning React is very easy if you already know Angular 2. It just makes you much more marketable. - http://www.typescriptlang.org/ - Expert, 1 Month.

In addition to just the core "`Angular 2`" framework, there are at least three other supplemental "power tools" you will need that help you to really be able to take `Angular 2` to its full potential.

`Angular-Cli` - The `Angular Command Line Interface (CLI)` allows you to quickly generate boilerplate `Angular 2` code files and perform a variety of useful tasks. I have found this tool to be indispensible, and it greatly enhances my productivity. - https://cli.angular.io/ - Expert, 1 Day

`Angular Universal` - Angular Universal is a tool for generating/rendering elements of `Angular 2` on the server rather than in the client's browser. This can dramatically improve load times and making the page more search-engine friendly. `Angular Universal` is a key component of `Search Engine Optimization` (`SEO`) with `Angular 2`. - Strong, 1 Week

`Reactive Extensions for JavaScript / RxJS` - `RxJS` is a library that provides core functionality for building modern Web applications. It's foundation component is an entity called an "`observable`." For the moment, `Observables` would be bit challenging to explain other than to say this. An `Observable` kind of "subscribes" to a piece of data and then allows the system to "do something" when that data changes. While this may seem trivial, it is not. It opens the door to much other functionality. This is an advanced concept used in `Angular 2`--and one we will explore deeply concurrent with learning that framework. - https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS - Strong, 3 Days

**Core Tools**

`NodeJS` - `NodeJS` is a `Javascript` "environment" based on the `JavaScript` engine found in Google Chrome. It allows you to run `JavaScript` applications outside of a Web browser. Most of the tools we will use involve `NodeJS` in one way or another. Initially, you will just need to develop a very basic familiarity with `NodeJS`, but you would be well served to deepen this knowledge over time. - https://nodejs.org/en/ - Basic, 4 Hours

`Node Package Manager / NPM` - The `Node Package Manager` (based on `NodeJS`) is the tool we use to download most of our other software and libraries. Almost every other package we have listed in this document is installed using `NPM`. It is a simple but indispensable tool. https://www.npmjs.com/ - Basic, 4 Hours

**Task Runners**

As noted in the `ES6` and `TypeScript` descriptions, there are often multiple steps to get your original source code files into a format where they can be deployed into production--or even run/viewed locally in your browser. To get your `ES6` files into old-style `ES5 JavaScript`, you will use `Babel`. To transpile your `TypeScript` files into `ES6` or `ES5`, you will use the `TypeScript compiler` (`tsc`). You will want to perform these translations every time you modify a file. Beyond simply compiling, there are often many other tasks you will repetitively perform such as moving files from your source code directory to your "build" directory (the directory where you will run the files) on your PC. `Sass` also will be converting your `SCSS` files to standard `CSS` files. Suffice it to say, there are many repetitive tasks that you will not want to do manually. A "task runner" will do them for you.

Two task runners we will use are `Gulp` and `Grunt`. `Gulp` and `Grunt` allow you to define a series of tasks into some "command" and then have that command (optionally) run automatically for you whenever there are file changes. `Gulp` is the primary task runner you will use. `Grunt` is kind of falling by the wayside but is still in widespread enough use that you will need to be familiar with it. There are also many "plugins" for these systems you will also become familiar with and use.

`Gulp` - http://gulpjs.com/ - Expert, 1 Day

`Grunt` - http://gruntjs.com/ - Strong, 4 Hours

**Build Systems**

While `Gulp` and `Grunt` can help you build and deploy your Web sites / Web applications, there are two other systems which are particularly suited to this task. You will eventually need to become very familiar with both of them. Angular 2 uses Webpack.

`SystemJS` - https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs - Expert, 1 Day

`Webpack` - https://webpack.github.io/ - Expert, 2 Days

`Docker` - Docker is technology used for packing sites into containers and deploying the site as a unit. It is relatively new, but the entire market is moving to use it. You will be well served to know it. - https://www.docker.com/ - Working, 1 Day

**Source Code Versioning and Control**

`Git` - When developing websites, you will need to be able to track your changes and roll back to a previous version if something goes "horribly wrong"--which it often will. `Git` is, by far, the most popular version control system. Also, many websites (like GitHub) allow you to use it to pull down software from their sites (called repositories.) You will want to be very familiar with `Git`. - https://git-scm.com/ - Basic, 4 Hours

**JavaScript Testing Tools**

Testing is a critical part of any development. It also happens to be one of the most time consuming. You will eventually get familiar with a number of different test tools--all of which perform slightly different functions.

`Jasmine` - `JavaScript` Unit Test Framework - https://jasmine.github.io/ - Strong, 1 Day

`Karma` - `JavaScript` Test Runner - https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html - Strong, 1 Day

`Protractor` - End to end (e2e) test Framework for `Angular` - http://www.protractortest.org/ - Strong, 1 Day

`Istanbul` - Code coverage analyzer for `JavaScript` - https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul - Strong, 1 Day

**.NET Development**

Once you master client-side development, you may decide you want to learn server-side development as well--or you may feel perfectly comfortable continuing to focus on the client. Either is fine. Just for the sake of completeness, here are the tools I genereally use for server-side development.

`ASP.NET Core` - Microsoft's new server-side web framework which runs on Windows, Linux, and OS/X. The framework is very robust and highly performant. ASP.NET is used by many businesses for developing core line-of-business applications. For example, many banks use `ASP.NET` or `ASP.NET Core` to develop Internet banking websites. - https://www.asp.net/core

`ASP.NET Identity` - This is the Microsoft library for handling user and account management. This is actually a large part of the functionality in any Web application and has a number of very complicated pieces. `ASP.NET Identity` does most of the heavy lifting but is also very extensible. - https://www.asp.net/identity

`ASP.NET SignalR` - `SignalR` allows for real-time communications between a client (typically) and a browser--generally using a technologically called Websockets. Some example applications might be real-time chat, massively multiplayer online games, or a real-time stock ticker. - https://www.asp.net/signalr

`Entity Framework 7 / Entity Framework Core` - Much of the effort required to code back-end applications relates to storing and retrieving data from a database. `Entity Framework` abstracts much of that functionality and provides a much simpler way to store and retrieve data. https://www.asp.net/entity-framework, https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework

`Microsoft SQL Server` - Microsoft's database implementation. `SQL Server` works well with other Microsoft tools. It is great, and I have been using versions of it since 1995. However, I sometimes use `MariaDB` (https://mariadb.org/) and have been considering using `PostgreSQL` (https://www.postgresql.org/) or `MongoDb` (https://www.mongodb.com/) for some future projects. There is a free version of `SQL Server` available for development. All of the other database platforms mentioned are already open source. - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2016

`Redis` - `Redis` is a super-fast in-memory database. It is used by most of the high-end websites (including Facebook) for data-caching. Use of `Redis` in conjunction with `SQL Server` or `MariaDb` can greatly improve the overall performance of a website.

`NUnit` - `NUnit` is a unit test framework for .NET--which I used on the back-end. https://www.nunit.org/

**Development Resources**

There are a number of websites I access on a regular basis to assist me with development. The most important site is `Stack Overflow` which has over 12 million questions and answers on almost any development topic. It is an invaluable resource, and I use it every day. You will definitely want to create a free account there. I also frequently access GitHub to download various software and use Google to query thousands of other sites for specific information.

`Stack Overflow` - https://stackoverflow.com/

`GitHub` - https://github.com/

Comment: Anthony, thanks for your detailed answer. The aim is to make one WebSocket connection for user session. I can make it with Angular 2/React or other SPA library or use only one view in ASP.NET MVC (and reload only its components, f.e. with the help of ViewComponent). Also I want to mark, that SignalR is still not available for .Net Core, thats why Websocket only the way

Comment: @Alex, yes, thankfully, SignalR Core is already available. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/

Comment: Anthony,   SignalR core library is not  asp.net core library(it's simply asp.net).  SignalR 3 for asp.net core will be available only in 2017

Comment: @Alex, Try this link. Here is the SignalR preview for ASP.NET Core. It is functional. https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/aspnetcore-ci-dev/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server

Comment: +1 for the great answer.
Would have given another +1 for VSCode instead of VS if I could.

Comment: what a gem of an answer! thanks @AnthonyGatlin!